# Use expand.grid to generate factor combinations with a specified frequency distribution?

Tags: r

Suppose I have:

```
data <- expand.grid(factor1 = c("a","b"),
                    factor2 = c("left","right"),
                    factor3 = c("up","down"))
```

Suppose I want to copy rows from this data frame such that I define the frequency distribution of each factor, and each row is copied as few times as is possible to satisfy that distribution. For example, if I defined the frequency of "factor1" to be (.5,.5), "factor2" to be (.25,.75), and "factor3" to be (.4,.6), then my data frame would have to have 2 X 4 X 5 = 40 total rows. I can do this:

```
data2 <- expand.grid(factor1 = c("a","b"),
                     factor2 = c("left",rep("right",3)),
                     factor3 = c(rep("up",2),rep("down",3)))
```

But that only works if I know the frequencies ahead of time - and even then, it seems inelegant to have to go from (.4,.6) to `c(rep("a",2),rep("b",3))` by hand like that. What's a better way to do this?

Comment: Instead of `c(rep("a",2),rep("b",3))`, you can write it equally `rep(c("a", "b"), c(2, 3))`. And if you set `factor1 <-  c("a","b")` and its frequency `freq1 <-c(2,3)` beforehand, it is `rep(factor1, freq1)`, which IMHO more readable.